# How do I sum all even or odd columns in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

The following is given as a solution for Excel:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(B16:AO16),2)=0,B16:AO16,0))
```

=0 changes to =1 to toggle between odd and even columns.  However, this doesn't work in Google Spreadsheets - unless the output of MOD goes to an array function, MOD just calculates against the first value in the range.

How can I do this in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(C1:F10))=TRUE,C1:F10)))
```

### Explained

The `ISODD` function will check if the column number is odd (`TRUE`). The `IF` function will return the number if `TRUE`, else `FALSE`. The `ARRAYFORMULA` does that for the complete range and the sum will simply sum up the numbers (and ignore the boolean results)

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[sum odd or even column ranges](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/12-PloFPrveUqhAkxt1Sc4iwcCiJnegv5zugckP6GUvQ/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 6):

Significantly shorter formula than [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/61059/88675):

```
=SUM(FILTER(C1:F10, ISODD(COLUMN(C1:F10))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this yields "unexpected column count" on the second argument. Sure enough, the `ISODD(...)` function appears to simply give a single value for the range.

Comment: Could you post an example? It is working for me for both even and odd column counts.

Comment: I don't have an example at hand at the moment, but I was selecting a single column range.

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me to sum values in every 3rd column, by changing `ISODD` to `MOD(<range>, 3)=0`, like so: `=SUM(FILTER(B3:F5, MOD(COLUMN(B3:F5),3)=0))`. I couldn't get the same effect by adapting the ARRAYFORMULA approach of the accepted answer (although it's probably possible).

Answer (score 2):

Even though this has an accepted answer, I wanted to find a non-array version of this for two reasons:
 1. I wanted a version that worked in Excel (2016, at least) as well, and
 2. I wanted to know if I could

I came up with this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$20,--(MOD(ROW($A$2:$A$20),2)=0))
```

If your numbers are in A2:A20, the above will sum the even-row numbers. change the last 0 to a 1 for Odd-row numbers.

Here are links to working examples in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18E-70L3G-J3sRAn5D9G5-Vf7rt735SI6nJZ1tjh0HkE/edit?usp=sharing) and [Excel Online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkYl_fMF4hJLk_F2nro5O6i2sN6lAg)

Comment: Nice! I like that this one can be adapted to work for any interval size, by replacing the second argument of the `MOD` function :)